# Simple demo project Webpack KO(with a components) javascript

Tags: javascript, webpack, knockout.js, knockout-components

I want to build a SPA with javascript knockout components
After lots of reading and fiddling I still can't seem to get a working javascript(no typescript) knockout( with components) project with webpack.
I found simple knockout projects but can't get them working with webpack.

Does someone have a demo project wit at least one ko component using webpack?

The Yeoman generator-ko-spa (in javascript) working with Webpack would be great.

Thnx

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow :) In order to get better answers and to avoid downvotes, please share what you have tried so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to set up a "Hello world" app from scratch:

### Installing packages

- Create a new folder
- Run `npm init -y`
- Install webpack related modules:

  - `npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-cli html-loader`
- For intellisense in your editor, install knockout

  - `npm install --save-dev knockout`
- Create a npm command in the scripts section:

  - `"scripts": { "build": "webpack" }`

### Configuring webpack

- Create a `webpack.config.js` file:

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "index.js"),
  module: {
    rules: [
      // This tells webpack to import required html files
      // as a string, through the html-loader
      { test: /\.html$/, use: [ "html-loader" ] }
    ],
  },
  // You *could* include knockout in your bundle, 
  // but I usually get it from a CDN
  externals: {
    knockout: "ko"
  }
}
```

### Creating our component viewmodel & view

- Create a folder named `Components`
- Create `Greeter.html`

```
<h1 data-bind="text: message">...</h1>
```

- Create `Greeter.js`

```
const greeterTemplate = require("./Greeter.html");

module.exports = {
  viewModel: function(params) {
    this.message = params.message;
  },
  template: greeterTemplate
};
```

### Creating our entry points

- Create an `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <greeter params="message: 'Hello world!'"></greeter>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

- Create an `index.js` file

```
const ko = require("knockout");
const greeter = require("./Components/Greeter");

ko.components.register("greeter", greeter);
ko.applyBindings({});
```

### Build & browser

- run `npm run build`, webpack will create a file in a `dist` folder
- Open `index.html` in your browser. It should greet you with a "Hello world"!

Comment: Thnx!  this works, only thing I had to change was:module.exports = {
  viewmodel yhis should be viewModel  with capital M otherwise the viewModel is not used.

Comment: Thanks @Geert , I fixed the typo.

Comment: This is the kind of answer that's often sorely lacking these days on SO. Kudos.

Comment: made it! thank you https://github.com/iagokrt/revisin