# Run external function when knockout component is created

Tags: webpack, knockout.js, webpack-html-loader

I am trying to create new component in knockout:

```
ko.components.register("categories", {
    viewModel: {
        instance: MY_VIEW_MODEL
    },
    template: require('html-loader?interpolate!./components/categories.html')
});
```

and my HTML block inside of ***categories.html***:

```
<div class="panel" data-bind="foreach: categories, afterRender: ${require('../effects.js').fadePanels()}"></div>
```

and inside of ***effect.js***:

```
function fadePanels() {
    $('.panel').velocity('fadeInPanels', {
        stagger: 250,
    })
}
```

plus ***webpack.config.js***:

```
    test: /\.html$/,
    loader: 'html-loader',
    options: {
        interpolate: true
    },
    exclude: /node_modules/
```

but it's not working at all. Here is the output from browser (no errors in console):
[image]

Do you have any experience with this? Do you know how to correctly handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a function that takes a component's element by using the `createViewmodel` factory method. This function receives an info object that includes the current `element`.

```js
ko.components.register("category", {
    viewModel: { 
      createViewModel: (params, info) => {
        fadeIn(info.element);
        return { label: "hello world" }
      } 
    },
    template: `<div data-bind="text: label"></div>`
});

const categories = ko.observableArray(["", "", ""]);
const addCat = () => categories.push("");

ko.applyBindings({ categories, addCat  });

function fadeIn(el) {
  el.classList.add("seeThrough");
  setTimeout(
    () => el.classList.add("fadeIn"), 
    200
  );
}
```

```css
.seeThrough {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.fadeIn {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: categories">
  <li data-bind="component: { name: 'category' }"></li>
</ul>

<button data-bind="click: addCat">add</button>
```

For working with components and webpack, you might want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52776921/3297291) I wrote a few days ago. It describes how to configure webpack to work with knockout components.

Comment: that's great! but what about the case I already have a view model with all of the categories inside (therefore I put the property instance to share the same model) and I just want to show them with some visual effect? should I still use 'createViewModel(..)' function? let's say I have already something like this in view model: categories = ko.observableArray([new Category("Category 1"), new Category("Category 2")]) and I just want to show the name of the category as unordered list in HTML.